# What is the term for paint which is suitable for our skin?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like paints which are ok to eat are called **edible** paints. What is the term we can use for paints which are suitable for our skin?

Comment: [This article from WorldSafety](https://www.worldsafety2018.org/what-paint-is-safe-for-skin/#-The-Verdict-) simply uses 'safe for the skin', giving a hint that no single-word term is available: << These products are FDA approved so they are safe for the skin and won’t cause irritation when applied. >> 'Skin-safe' seems to follow the rules for productive extending of the lexis, but those who say that it's therefore a word never seem to provide  authoritative references for such a claim. Appearance in reputable dictionaries / articles is the best guide for wordness.

Comment: *Body paint* could also work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

It’s called **body paint**. Paints that can also be used on your face (which is more sensitive) are sometimes more specifically called **face and body paints**.

For example:

- > [F]or the sake of this article we will characterize products used on the face as makeup or face paint and products used on the full body as body paint.  —[How to Choose Your Bodypaint](https://www.trinamerry.com/body-painting-nyc/blog/2018/5/14/how-to-choose-your-bodypaint)
- [Face & Body Paint Kit](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Face-Body-Paint-Kit-12-Colors-Professional-Face-Painting-Kits-Contains-with-Rich-Pigment-and-2-Brushes-Suitable-for-Face-and-Body-Painting/973593354)
- [UV Glow Blacklight Face and Body Paint 0.34oz - Set of 6 Tubes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BUPN6UA)